# Website to get in contact with an interface designer?

Tags: interface-design, applications

is there a popular website where I can order an interface design for an application to a fixed price or make an auction style request? Maybe something where I can browse the previous work of that designer?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with graphic design. You might be able to migrate this to ux.stackexchange.com but its not really about user interfaces either.

Answer (score 0):

Peopleperhour.com if you havnt got much to spend, elance.com or freelancers.net if you don't mind paying proper rates :) All worldwide sites, Good luck.

Comment: And http://www.99designs.com would be a choice.